# combine two tables and sum mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

i want to join two tables but i can't do it as i want to sum column and get the result between two dates

first table named : vip_allotment_details

```
allotment_id    qty
2                3
2                5
1                2
1                4
```

the second table name : vip_allotment

```
id   date_from  date_to
1    2017-10-1  2017-10-5
2    2017-10-6  2017-10-10
```

what i want from the query to get me this result

```
id    qty  date_from   date_to
1      6   2017-10-1   2017-10-5
2      8   2017-10-6   2017-10-10
```

i will explain the result :

first allotment_id field is linked with id field in second table , the result i want that we can make sum of qty by the two fields (id , allotment_id ) between the date_from and date_to

and here is my try  :

```
$query1 = "
SELECT SUM(qyt) as total
   FROM vip_allotment_details 
 where allotment_id IN ( SELECT id from vip_allotment where date_from >= '$date_1' AND date_to <= '$date_2') 
";
```

In my query the result gets all the sum of qty field with no filter ..

I hope I have explained my problem well .

thanks/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not try yet, but maybe you can try like this:

```
SELECT a.id AS id, SUM(qyt) AS qty, date_from, date_to
FROM vip_allotment AS a
LEFT JOIN vip_allotment_details AS b on b.allotment_id = a.id
WHERE a.date_from >= '{thedatestart}' AND a.date_to <= '{thedateend}'
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id ASC;
```

Comment: thanks man it works but i need to make date range on it like date_from >= 'something' and date_to <= 'something' wish you tell me how to apply it on your query

Comment: Ok, just put WHERE clause on that query `WHERE a.date_from >= '{thedatestart}' AND a.date_to <= '{thedateend}'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..change your table name and run the query..hopefully  it should give the result as your requirement..if not let me know...

```
select a.id
     , sum(b.qty)
     , a.date_from
     , a.date_to 
  from table1 a
     , table2 b 
 where a.id = b.allotment_id 
 group 
    by b.allotment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOIN`. I see you are using `IN` keyword, which won't work. There can be many ways to solve your problem. One of them is,

```
select allotment_id, qty, date_from, date_to
from 
(select allotment_id, SUM(qty) as qty 
   from vip_allotment_details group by allotment_id
) at
INNER JOIN 
vip_allotment va 
ON va.id= at.allotment_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more then one result form an aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, AVG, ...) you'll need to use a GROUP BY. Your query isn't that hard, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT va.id, va.date_from, va.date_to, SUM(vad.qyt) AS qyt
FROM vip_allotment AS va
LEFT JOIN vip_allotment_details AS vad ON vad.allotment_id = va.id
GROUP BY va.id
```

And as you can see here, this produces the expected result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/707a8/2

If you now want to start adding extra filters (like filter by date), you can just do so by adding a `WHERE` to the query. Something like this:

```
...
LEFT JOIN ...
WHERE va.date_from >= "2017-10-06" and va.date_to <= "2018-10-06"
GROUP BY ...
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/707a8/6

On a side note, I noticed you are not binding your params in the php part of your code . Do note that this can pose serious security issues, especially if these dates come directly from the user input. I would suggest looking in to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to do the actual querying in PHP.

Comment: i really appreciate it and it work man thanks , but i want to make a range like from date_from to date_to as a filter to the result

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do what you ask.

```
SELECT 
    va.id,
    SUM(vad.qyt) AS total,
    va.date_from,
    va.date_to
FROM vip_allotment_details AS vad 
LEFT JOIN vip_allotment AS va ON va.id = vad.allotment_id
GROUP BY vad.allotment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.i think you will get your desired result.

```
select va.id, temp.qty , va.date_from,va.date_to from vip_allotment as va
inner join (select sum(qty) as qty , allotment_id from vip_allotment_details group by `allotment_id`) as temp
ON temp.allotment_id=va.id 
where va.date_from >= '$date_1' AND va.date_to <= '$date_2';
```